# SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(unrecognized token: "498a" (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Products WHERE

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to delete any rows that contains a certain productGuid from my SQFLite database. so I am passing a guid to a method and try to do it by this code:

```
await db
          .rawDelete("DELETE FROM Products WHERE productGuid = $productGuid");
```

I am able to read and insert data from and to my database so my database is correctly initialized. I cannot find the problem so any help would be appreciated.
here is the complete error that I get:

> Exception has occurred. SqfliteDatabaseException
>   (DatabaseException(unrecognized token: "498a" (code 1): , while
>   compiling: DELETE FROM Products WHERE productGuid =
>   c2789c01-c972-498a-9396-096c9be49d5c) sql 'DELETE FROM Products WHERE
>   productGuid = c2789c01-c972-498a-9396-096c9be49d5c' args []})

Comment: see the examples here: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite - notice how `rawDelete` is called - do the same with your `rawDelete`

Comment: yes thanks. it worked as I wanted